# Install service remotely without using WMI, PsExec or TopShelf?

Tags: c#, .net, service, remote-access

I need to install / uninstall services on remote machines from C# code.

I can't use WMI due to firewall issues.
I prefer not to use PsExec to remotely call SC.exe or using `SC.exe \\server create` locally as those options requires text parsing of the output.

TopShelf is not an option as well.

For starting / stopping I used [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class with Impersonation.

Comment: Can you put it into the users' login/logoff scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file for the installation/uninstallation procedure and register it to a scheduled task to run once the minute after you create it and enable it. Use this library to manage scheduled tasks remotely:

http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Set a delay on your task to wait one minute, check the exit code, then delete the job.